# Gradle - cannot instantiate ivy class

Tags: groovy, gradle

What am I doing wrong here? The ultimate goal is to download *.properties from the URL.

[ I know resolver is not needed, was just trying out to see if there was a class name issue. ]

Error:

```
    build file '/home/awm/t/build.gradle': 13: unable to resolve class org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver 
   @ line 13, column 20.
         def resolver = new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()
                        ^

  build file '/home/awm/t/build.gradle': 14: unable to resolve class org.apache.ivy.util.url.ApacheURLLister 
   @ line 14, column 21.
         def urlLister = new org.apache.ivy.util.url.ApacheURLLister()
                         ^
```

Code:

```
plugins {
    id "de.undercouch.download" version "2.0.0"
}

import de.undercouch.gradle.tasks.download.Download
import org.apache.ivy.util.url.*

task downloadDirectory {
    def dir = 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/artifactory/gradle-local/props/'
    def resolver = new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()
    def urlLister = new org.apache.ivy.util.url.ApacheURLLister()
    def files = urlLister.listFiles(new URL(dir))
    download {
       src files
       dest "lib"
    }
}

defaultTasks 'downloadDirectory'
```

Answer (score 0):

From Gradle 2.0 on you need to include a build script dependency to Apache Ivy in order to make this recipe work. Put the following right at the beginning of your build script.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.3.0'
    }
}
```

example: https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task/blob/ddb384d3ee86f038c61ec4e77f21b814b1557a1a/examples/directory.gradle

another use-cases of download task: https://www.michel-kraemer.com/recipes-for-gradle-download/